# Canceling events after the .after() method has been called on them?

Tags: python, events, canvas, tkinter

I'm writing a little game with python tkinter module using a canvas widget.
There is the person, who is just a ball, and bombs that spawn every 10 seconds.
3 seconds after a bomb spawns, it begins a process of "exploding" which I call 4 more methods on the self.bomb object to "animate" it exploding.

The object of the game is to try to "disarm" the bombs. I've come up with some fancy collision detection which is working. Once a collision is detected, the bomb is cleared off of the canvas using:

```
self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
```

However, the following animation of the bomb getting bigger and changing color (exploding) still happens, even if I've "disarmed" the bomb. This is because my original bomb calls:

```
self.parent.after(3000, self.explode_first)
```

... which I have chained 3 more "explode" functions, all bound and called with the .after() method.

I tried to circumvent the problem by inserting conditionals into each of the methods called in the .after(), like booleans;

```
if self.bomb # if there's a bomb on the canvas,
     self.parent.after(125, self.explode_second) # and explode third and so on
```

which is not working. I want to be able to "cancel" events the tkinter queue that have been created with the after method, but here is the kicker. I don't(cant) kill ALL the events, just the ones on the canvas. I have other events going that I want to leave intact, if possible.

Is there a way to do this? If not, feedback and/or suggestions on how to do this without canceling after events are welcomed, and Thanks in advance!

Heres the relevant code, for reference:

```
def start_game(self):
    self.Bombs += 1
    self.bombsLabel.configure(text = "Total Bombs: %d" % self.Bombs)
    self.b1 = random.randint(1, int(self.canvas.winfo_width()))
    self.b2 = random.randint(1, int(self.canvas.winfo_height()))
    self.b3 = self.b1 + 20
    self.b4 = self.b2 + 20
    self.create_bomb()
    self.parent.after(10000, self.start_game)
```

and :

```
# continuously make and explode bombs
def create_bomb(self):
    self.bomb = self.canvas.create_oval(self.b1, 
                                        self.b2, 
                                        self.b3, 
                                        self.b4, 
                                        fill = "red")
    if self.bomb:
        self.parent.after(3000, self.explode_first)


def explode_first(self):
    if self.bomb:
        self.b1 -= 5
        self.b2 -= 5
        self.b3 += 5
        self.b4 += 5
        self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
        self.bomb = self.canvas.create_oval(self.b1, 
                                        self.b2, 
                                        self.b3, 
                                        self.b4, 
                                        fill = "orange")
        self.parent.after(125, self.explode_second)


def explode_second(self):
    if self.bomb:
        self.b1 -= 5
        self.b2 -= 5
        self.b3 += 5
        self.b4 += 5
        self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
        self.bomb = self.canvas.create_oval(self.b1, 
                                        self.b2, 
                                        self.b3, 
                                        self.b4, 
                                        fill = "yellow")
        self.parent.after(125, self.explode_third)


def explode_third(self):
    self.b1 -= 5
    self.b2 -= 5
    self.b3 += 5
    self.b4 += 5
    self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
    self.bomb = self.canvas.create_oval(self.b1,
                                        self.b2,
                                        self.b3,
                                        self.b4, 
                                        fill = "white")
    self.parent.after(125, self.explode_fourth)


def explode_fourth(self):
    self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)

def bomb_disarmed(self):

    print "disarmed the bomb!"
    self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
```

Comment: Update: So, I've used canvas.find_above(self.ball): as a conditional, which seems to work. However looking through the docs for tkinter canvas this seems sloppy, and if I don't disarm the bomb, it remains there forever now, where as before they would explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an attribute to the class that you're working like this:

```
self.isDisarmed = False
```

Then add this line to `bomb_disarmed`:

```
self.isDisarmed = True
```

Then in `explode_first`, add a test to see if the bomb has been disarmed:

```
def explode_first(self):
    if self.bomb:
        if self.isDisarmed:
            self.parent.after(125, self.explode_fourth)   # If bomb is disarmed, skip to the last step, where the bomb is deleted.
        else:                                             # Otherwise, carry on with bomb explosion
            self.b1 -= 5
            self.b2 -= 5
            self.b3 += 5
            self.b4 += 5
            self.canvas.delete(self.bomb)
            self.bomb = self.canvas.create_oval(self.b1, 
                                            self.b2, 
                                            self.b3, 
                                            self.b4, 
                                            fill = "orange")
            self.parent.after(125, self.explode_second)
```

As a general principle, I would recommend making `Bomb` a class, which has its own internal attributes and methods.  That will make it easier to keep track of what is happening to the bomb, and what the result should be, and it will make it possible to do things like have multiple bombs.

EDIT:

Re: drawing on an `App`'s canvas from another class's method, here's one way:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(...)
        self.thingy = SomethingElse()

class SomethingElse:
    def __init__(self, parentApp):
        self.parentApp = parentApp
    def drawSomething(self):
        self.parentApp.canvas.create_oval(...)

a = App(...)
s = SomethingElse(a)
s.drawSomething()
```

Comment: I totally agree with the second bit there, (i'll work on implementing and testing the first bit) but I really struggled to be able to add other objects into the canvas I initialized in my main class. Any pointers there? it seemed that I couldn't access the App class's canvas any way other than with methods I build into the same class.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. As long as you pass the canvas object to another method, that method should be able to draw on the canvas, regardless of what class the method belongs to.

Comment: But either way, it would be cleaner to have the `App` class's methods handle all the drawing, and just have the `Bomb` class "request" that it be drawn by calling a method from the `App` class.

Comment: Usually I see a "canvas" not defined, or something similar I believe. I know it shouldn't work with the self. tag, but putting App.canvas.some_method was causing stuff to freak out.

Comment: Also, I resolved the issue I was seeing by a if not: block, but your answer led me to it, so I'll mark as accepted, and your other suggestion is invaluable. I'll buckle down and add the other classes I need now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `after` method returns an id that represents the scheduled event. If you save the id, you can call `after_cancel` to cancel the event:

```
self.after_id = self.parent.after(3000, self.explode_first)
...
self.parent.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the after_cancel() method
from docs:

```
w.after_cancel(id)
Cancels a request for callback set up earlier .after(). The id argument is the result returned by the original .after() call.
```